# How can I recall last method state in iOS?

Tags: ios, uilabel

I just can't get my head around this and possibly my title isn't perfectly clear.  I am a newbie, learning how to program.  I am creating a simple calculator and when the user selects any operand, the title of the operand changes its color from white to orange.  I setup a switch statement and change setTitleColor.  As soon as a digit is pressed the operand button returns to original state of color white.  What I want to do is if the user then presses the clear button once, change the color of the last highlighted operand back to orange.

I am just stuck trying to figure out a way to return back one step.  If anyone can give me an idea of how I can achieve this, I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing specific to iOS here. All you need to so is probably have a stack maintained or a simple `lastUpdatedDigit` variable tracking the last action performed. Here in your app  its the last digit typed.

So when you want to change the color of the last highlighted operand back to orange all you need to do is access this `lastUpdatedDigit` variable & change its color. You are good to go.

Not sure if this answers your question. If i have misunderstood, then please correct...

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. You understand exactly what I want to accomplish.  I will update when I get the logic down and hopefully perfected code.

Comment: @d.altman glad to share. in the spirit of this community please try to upvote & check mark accepted answer, thanks..

Comment: Srikar, So I have 4 operands and I need to track lastOperandPressed so say the user clicks a digit and then an operand and then clicks several more digits and then clear I will know which lastOperandPressed. I’m stuck trying to find an efficient way to track this.  In my clear method I am thinking of having an if statement like if lastOperandPressed == button1 then change titleColor of it, etc.  Any more hints or ideas welcomed.

Comment: I'm probably going to wear out my welcome and test your patience. I'm stuck trying to figure out how to track which operand is the lastOperandPressed.

Comment: You helped be so much. It took me a while but I am able to track the lastOperatorPressed. Thank you for leading me to the water!